# Update table records when session timeout without page load

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

1. Installed pip install django-session-timeout
2. updated setting.py like this

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
   # ...
   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
   'caccounts.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware', # custom middleware
   # ... ]
   ```

And also add the:

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS = 3600  # 1 hour
SESSION_EXPIRE_AFTER_LAST_ACTIVITY = True
```

I wrote some code in my custom middleware like below

```
current_user = request.user  
user = User.objects.get(pk=current_user.id)  
user.is_online = False    
user.save()
```

Its update status only when i load page but i want to update status automatically while timeout session

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you need to write your middleware like this:

```
class CustomMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response


    def __call__(self, request):
        if not hasattr(request, 'session') or request.session.is_empty():
            return

        init_time = request.session.setdefault(SESSION_TIMEOUT_KEY, time.time())

        expire_seconds = getattr(
            settings, 'SESSION_EXPIRE_SECONDS', settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE)

        session_is_expired = time.time() - init_time > expire_seconds
        current_user = request.user
        user = User.objects.get(pk=current_user.id)  
        if session_is_expired:
           user.is_online = False    
           user.save()
        # put next block of code if necessary
        # else:
        #   if user.is_online == False:
        #      user.is_online = True
        #      user.save()   
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

**FYI** you need to put this `CustomMiddleware` before `'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware'` in *settings.py* because `SessionTimeoutMiddleware` flushes the session after timeout.

Comment: Thank you for your information but the status updated only when i'm login not session timeout. I need status automatically when session is expired

Comment: I think for that, you need to write some sort of cronjob. You can look into celery. :)